# Rust lifetimes for str and String

Tags: rust

I am learning about lifetimes from the rust book.

One quick question,

This following code is giving an expected error which is correct:

```rust
fn check_check() {
    let r; 
    {
        let s = String::from("s");
        r = check(&s); // says s does not live long enough
    }
    println!("{}", r);
}

fn check<'a>(s: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    return s;
}
```

This is because I have mentioned the lifetimes in the check function to be same as the argument. So this is fine which I understand.

By the same logic, when I write this code, this DOES NOT GIVE ANY ERRORS.

Which is something I don't understand, how is this able to compile?

```
fn check_check() {
    let r; 
    {
        let s = "a";
        r = check(&s); // works just fine, why? and how?
    }
    println!("{}", r);
}

fn check<'a>(s: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `'a` is inferred to be `'static`?

Comment: It's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292404/why-do-generic-lifetimes-not-conform-to-the-smaller-lifetime-of-a-nested-scope) plus some deref coercion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we ask about lifetimes, there is a question about types here: the type of string literals is `&'static str`, and when you take a reference to it you get `&&'static str` (two references), so how can you pass it to a function that expects `&str` (one reference)?

And the answer is that when passing an argument into a function, the compiler may do coercion adjustments; and one of the adjustments possible is deref coercion, which dereferences the value passed. So we take the `&&'static str` and dereference it to get `&'static str`.

And this is the answer to your question too: since we pass `&'static str`, `'a` is `'static`, so it does live long enough.